# Optional, dangerous permission READ_PHONE_STATE not granted on Android 8 and 9?

Tags: android, user-permissions

In my application I want to check if the user receives a phone call (no need to get any phone details like phone number). Therefore I want to access the dangerous rated READ_PHONE_STATE permission in my fragment at runtime like this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Application.getActiveActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Application.getActiveActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
}
```

In my activity I am handling the permission result as follows:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        // success, do fancy stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // show alert
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Not forgetting to add the permissions in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:requiredFeature="false"/>
```

(the permission is marked as non-required because the app is working not only on phones but on tablets as well)

This code is working as intended for Android 6 and 7. A popup is displayed, asking the user for permission to access the phone state. Depending on the user's selection, the grantResults in the activity's `onPermissionsResult()` are either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. So far, so good.

My problem here is that the behaviour is different with Android 8 and 9. Although I am asking for the READ_PHONE_STATE permissions in my fragment, there is never a popup displayed asking the user for granting them. So, the grantResults in my activity's `onPermissionsResult()` are always PERMISSION_DENIED.

I've also tried to manually activate the phone permissions in the app settings, but the phone permissions aren't even listed (despite to Android 6 and 7).

I've read that Android wants to restrict the usage of phone and SMS access for apps in 2019. But other apps like WhatsApp are still capable of using the phone permission. Is there something I am missing? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the `requiredFeature` flag in the AndroidManifest is causing the trouble here. When removed, the permission check is working as it should. Now I'm trying to find out how to use the phone permission AND support tablet devices not being capable of these features.

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to @Malv I found out that the root of my problem was the optional READ_PHONE_STATE permission. I did some research and found out that in order to archieve what I want, I have to declare the permission as required. In addition, if the phone permission should be an optional feature (allowing tablets to download the app as well) I have to use an additional  parameter, specifying the telephony feature as optional.

Here is my updated AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permissions not being requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703214/android-permissions-not-being-requested)

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:requiredFeature="false"` ?

Comment: @Malv This seems to be the problem here. When removing the optional `requiredFeature`, the permissions seem to work again. Now I just need to find a way to keep the READ_PHONE_STATE an optional permission. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need this permission you need to remove `android:requiredFeature="false"`. You just want to ask the user whether to allow using the permission or denying it.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element):

> When you declare `android:required="false"` for a feature, it means
>   that the application prefers to use the feature if present on the
>   device, but that it is designed to function without the specified
>   feature, if necessary.